# Is there a way to tell if an event has been handled in a previous bubbling phase?

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events, event-bubbling

In JS, is there a way to tell if an event was already handled in a prior bubbling phase before it reached the `currentTarget`?

My use case for this behavior is as follows:

I am making a website that is structured as a bunch of `div`s on top of each other. They are all a minimum of `100vh`. Sort of like this:

```css
div {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
div:first-child {
  background-color: yellow;
}
div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: purple;
}
div:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

In my application, there is a menu that will auto scroll to the `div`s that correspond to the menu items.  This is all well and good.

The problem comes when, rather than using the menu, the user just scrolls through the page manually. When this happens it is hard to get the section to line up perfectly with the  top and bottom of the page using the mouse wheel. Using this snippet as an example, go into full-screen and you may notice that it is impossible to get the purple `div` lined up perfectly using only the mouse wheel. (depends on your mouse I guess)

I would like to have it so that if the user clicks inside one of the sections, the page will automatically scroll so that the section is perfectly aligned with the borders of the page.

The caveat here is that I only want to do this if the event was **not** handled by some other handler in some prior bubbling phase. For example, if the user clicks a button inside of the section, then the handler for the auto-focus needs to be able to detect this and decide not to perform the operation.

I prefer not to resort to setting some variable in the earlier occurring handler. Nor do I want to stop the event from bubbling all together, simply because there are many types of events that could occur within a section and I prefer not be repeating code/calling the same function in a whole bunch of my event handlers just so this one can work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

By default, your click event is likely going to bubble up to parent elements, unless you explicitly [stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) in the handlers for the nested elements.

If you're using a library like jQuery, you can stop propagation on multiple elements with only a few lines of code.

HTML:

```
<div class="primary">
    <a href="#">Stop propagation!</a>
    <button>Also stop propagation!</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.primary').on('click', function() {
    alert('primary clicked!');
});

$('.primary a, .primary button').on('click', function(e) {
    alert('stop propagation');
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```